# Disable SA, Create New Login, Change Database Role Membership to db owner

Tags: sql-server, docker, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to write a test `T-SQL` script in `SSMS` that disables the `SA` user, creates a new `sysadmin` and enables `db owner` for all databases just like the `SA` user.

```
    USE [master]
    GO
    
    /****** Create New Login ******/
    CREATE LOGIN [bob] WITH PASSWORD = '!Bob1'
    GO
    
    /****** Change Server Role ******/
    ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [bob]
    GO
    
    /****** Change Role Membership ******/
    EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'bob'
    GO
    
    /****** Disable SA ******/
    ALTER LOGIN [sa] DISABLE
    GO
    
    /****** Create Database ******/
    CREATE DATABASE [test]
    GO
```

However, when I run the script I get this error:

> Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 13]
> User or role 'bob' does not exist in this database.

I know I can right click, go to properties, go to User Mapping, and manually select `db owner` for all the databases, but the intention behind the script is to run it in a MSSQL Docker container at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LOGIN` and `USER` are 2 completely different objects. A `LOGIN` is an instance level object, and a `USER` is a database object.

For a `sysadmin` there is no need to `CREATE` them a `USER` in the databases *unless* you're planning to migrate the database to another instance where a `LOGIN` with the same SID exists and it does not have `sysadmin` rights.

A `sysadmin` can do *whatever* it wants on an instance, without any mapped `USER` objects to it. It also ignores any explicit `DENY` permissions. Therefore, if it truly is just there to be a `sysadmin` then creating a `USER` in each database, and then giving that `USER` the `db_owner` role isn't needed. When a `sysadmin` connects to a database they automatically inherit the permissions from the `USER` `dbo`; which gives them free rein in the database.

If you are creating a `LOGIN` and related `USER`, then then correct syntax would be as below:

```sql
USE master;
GO

CREATE LOGIN YourPrinciple WITH PASSWORD = N'Some really secure password 123 (*&AT';

ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER YourLogin;
GO

USE YourDatabase;
GO
CREATE USER YourPrinciple FOR LOGIN YourPrinciple;

ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER YourPrinciple;
GO
```

FYI, don't use `sp_addrolemember`; it is due to be removed from SQL Server. Use `ALTER ROLE`, as demonstrated above.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about `sp_addrolemember` and the answer.  I think this is making sense now, so your basically saying if I didn't want a `User` database object, which I don't in my case, my new `bob` - `LOGIN` instance can do what he pleases even if `db owner` is not mapped to any db in `User Mapping`?

Comment: You are giving the **`LOGIN`** called `bob` the **Server** Role `sysadmin` @user1574598 . A `sysadmin` can *literally* do **anything** on an instance. And by literally, I do actually mean *literally*.

Comment: Great, I understand now, so there was nothing wrong with my script except for the `sp_addrolemember` line.  I will also take on board your script solution for a `User` database object for cases which you explained in your answer.  I think I got confused because I noticed `db owner` was selected for the `dbo` User for `master`, `model`, msdb`, and `tempdb` when right clicking on `sa` and going to User Mapping, but wasn't selected for my new `bob` - `LOGIN`.  Did you say at one point `sysadmin` inherits from `dbo`?  Apologies if incorrect.

Comment: No, it wasn't the use of `sp_addrolemember`, @user1574598 , it was that you were trying to give a `USER` that didn't exist (`bob`) the database role `db_owner`. You can't give roles to users that don't exist.

Comment: Right okay that makes sense too now, so if I change my connection string in my application to use `bob` instead of `sa` which is the current setup, everything should work exactly the same.  Sorry did you say in your post in a previous edit something about `sysadmin` inheriting from `dbo`?

Comment: *"if I change my connection string in my application to use"* Your application shouldn't have `sa`/`sysadmin` access in the first place, @user1574598 . It should have a `LOGIN` and `USER`s with the **minimal** needed permissions to do the task it is designed for.

Comment: Point taken, I will literally stick to your script then with a `LOGIN` and `USER`, its just a habit I've got into when doing local development with my SQL Server Docker database.